# using bash to attach states between tags

Tags: python, bash, xpath, sed, grep

I used `grep` command to extract everything between `<cite> </cite>` in file.xml:

```
grep -Po "(?<=<cite>).*?(?=</cite>)" /tmp/file.xml
```

The results are something like this:

```
<strong>site.com</strong>/<strong>blahblah</strong>/foo  #and may be with more tags named strong
<strong>site2.com</strong>/req/?<strong>blahblah2</strong>=foo
```

Now I want to have results like this:

```
site.com/blahblah/foo
site2.com/req/?blahblah2=foo
```

I want to remove add `<strong>` and `</strong>` and attach others...

If there is a way to use `xpath` in **python** this is also welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed:

```
 grep -Po "(?<=<cite>).*?(?=</cite>)" /tmp/file.txt | sed 's:<[^>]*>::g'
```

will delete everything between `<...>`

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your `grep` to this `sed` to remove all `<strong>` and `</strong>` tags:

```
sed -r 's#</?strong>##g'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo "<strong>site.com</strong>/<strong>blahblah</strong>/foo" | sed -e 's/<strong>//g' -e 's/<\/strong>//g'
```

Output

```
site.com/blahblah/foo
```